# How can I make a transfer from wallet to wallet in Decentraland

Tags: go-ethereum, erc-20, ether, metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm developing a small scene in Decentraland where I want to reward MANA for completing a mission. How can I make such a contract to transfer MANA to the player from my wallet right on the Decentraland stage, when player complete mission? Is it possible?

```
await crypto.mana.send(playerWallet, value, true).then(
    //log("s")
  )
```

As far as I understand, this function takes the address of the MetaMask wallet from which the call is made, and makes a transfer to the wallet specified in the arguments
Can i use transferFrom(), allowance(), approve() methods for this?

Thanks in advance